# error with puma in local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

I recently added puma to my app for better performance on heroku. my app works well in production (live)  environment but I am getting and error in my local environment..

error when I try to start my server:

```
Art West@ARTWESTIV ~/desktop/drinkPGH (master)
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[11868] *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
[11868] *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
[11868] *** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
[11868] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[11868] * Version 3.0.2 (ruby 2.1.5-p273), codename: Plethora of Penguin Pinatas
[11868] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[11868] * Environment: development
[11868] * Process workers: 2
[11868] * Preloading application
[11868] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Exiting
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-3.0.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:320:in `trap': unsupported signal SIGCHLD (ArgumentError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-3.0.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:320:in `setup_signals'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-3.0.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:389:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-3.0.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:173:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-3.0.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:51:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

and my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass'


group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'puma'  
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'

end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

my config.puma

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: what does your config/puma.rb file look like?

Comment: posted my config/puma.rb file! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not positive this will solve your problem. I usually run the app locally using foreman. The puma documentation for rails suggests starting your local server like this:

```
rails s Puma
```

For what it's worth.

Comment: posted my config/puma.rb file

Comment: What OS are you using? Cluster mode won't work w/ every OS. From docs:

"Platform Constraints

Because of various platforms not being able to implement certain things, the following differences occur when Puma is used on different platforms:

JRuby, Windows: server sockets are not seamless on restart, they must be closed and reopened. These platforms have no way to pass descriptors into a new process that is exposed to ruby
JRuby, Windows: cluster mode is not supported due to a lack of fork(2)
Windows: daemon mode is not supported due to a lack of fork(2)"

Comment: ah, I am using W10 so is there a way i can disable puma in dev only?

Comment: haven't done it but I'm sure you prob can. Maybe try moving the gem to a prod block and then in the config file say something like if Rails.env.production? 

not sure that will work but makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

```
 workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
```

(Not a fix) by commenting line 1 of config/puma.rb, I was able to run puma in development.

or

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 0) also works
```