# Rails 5: error when booting Puma on Windows 10 localhost install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, puma

I have Rails 5 localhost install on Windows 10 and when booting Puma I get this message in console:

```
PS C:\Sites\mysite> Puma
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

My Ruby version is 2.3.3.

In my *config/puma.rb* I have only these lines:

```
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Solution [mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735275/error-with-puma-in-local-server) did not work for me.

**How do I fix this, please?**

Comment: it looks like its running correctly? its running on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost though

Comment: It opens http://localhost:3000/ correctly. It's just I see that `SIGUSR2 not implemented` message, which probably is not OK.

Comment: I think its just because its running in single mode as opposed to the default of cluster mode, since windows doesn't support it. I wouldn't worry too much about it, unless you really need cluster mode. https://github.com/puma/puma#user-content-platform-constraints

Comment: I don't need cluster mode on my local PC in development. It's just I was thinking if this is some serious error I should worry about.